# Encoding over SSH Issues

Tags: ssh, vim, terminal, plugins, encoding

I have a Linux machine and a Windows machine, both using Vim with the Powerline plugin. They both work great with patched fonts. Next, I want to SSH onto an OSX 10.6 machine and also use the Powerline in the terminal with Vim. However, I get weird symbols with normal mode ("^^B" in one area) and fancy mode ("~@" and "~B") spread throughout the bar. I thought this mixup was an encoding issue, but when I look at Putty's encoding it is using UTF-8 and the same with the Ubuntu terminal. Additionally, on the OSX machine, "locale" returns "en_US.UTF-8" for all variables (I set it to do that in order to troubleshoot). However, the symbols are still showing. I am using a patched font (Inconsolata, the same one as the Ubuntu terminal) for the OSX terminal, so I am stumped. Is there a missing component to this equation? Are there additional problems that can arise from SSH encoding? On the OSX end, additionally, these same symbols appear, so it may not even be related to SSH and therefore I'm totally lost.

Comment: What `env|grep TERM` are reporting on the target machines when you are connected to the linux machine and to the OSX?

Comment: Both Putty and the Linux terminal are using xterm-256color when connecting to the OSX.

Comment: Then I have no more ideas - it was just a guess.

Comment: Would `set encoding=utf-8` and `set termencoding=utf-8` help?

Comment: I already had the former in my .vimrc, but adding the latter did not help.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. I was avoiding MacVim because I wanted to use the terminal, but I caved in and discovered that I can run it in the terminal with -v, so it works now after doing that and cleaning the cache.